# OsCommerce - Remove osCsid in urls

Tags: seo, e-commerce, oscommerce

I discovered that Google has indexed the osCsid parameter in some of my URLs at my osCommerce application. I tried to find a solution but I don't want to do something if I'm not sure what I'm doing.
I only have access to the FTP and not the CMS system. Is it possible to solve this problem through the FTP?

Answer (score 2):

In your product_info.php add the following in the head section

```
<link rel="canonical" href="<?php echo tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . (int)$_GET['products_id'],NONSSL,false); ?>" />
```

This will tell the search engines to use this url instead of the one being crawled, that contains the session id in it. This has been call more of a *hint* and not a *directive*, so there are other factors in play.

You also asked if you can do it with ftp access, yes you can.

Good resource on the topic:
http://forums.oscommerce.com/topic/330479-what-is-the-oscsid-why-you-must-not-loose-it/

Comment: i have added to ur code in my oscommerce 2.3.1 product info page but still it is not working..

Comment: @Jimmy You first need to make sure that the "rel" attribute is showing on the tag. If it is, you must wait for Google to re-index your site, which can take a while. If it is not, you must check that you are uploading the changes correctly